# files' random modify time

Tags: 12.04

I'v checked around the net and I learn how to change the modify time for files, after that they have the same modify time, its not my willing, I want to have the random time, which is better for secure,  can anyone tell me how to do?

Comment: What does a modify time have to do with security?

Comment: He's trying to make his own timestomp utility.  It's post-exploitation anti-security.

Answer (score 0):

The first challenge is generating a random date. Here's what I came up with.

```
date -d @$(shuf -i "0-$(date +%s)" -n 1) +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S
```

Working from the inside-out:

- `date +%s` gets the current date as a Unix timestring (seconds into the Epoc, since 1970)
- `shuf` uses that as an upper bound for a random number from 0
- `date` converts that back into something we can use.

Then there's the setting the mtime on a file. Thankfully `touch` makes this *really* simple:

```
touch -mt <[[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss]> <filename>
```

So we just need to loop over files and chain these two together:

```
find -type f -exec sh -c 'touch -m -t $(date -d @$(shuf -i "0-$(date +%s)" -n 1) +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S) "{}"' \;
```

There's a bit of padding in there to stop the date being randomly generated outside the loop but this does work:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oli oli 0 Jan  4  2012 1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oli oli 0 Jan 28  2009 2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oli oli 0 Jun  8  1984 3
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs into this, this command works for me to set a random date from 1st January 1970 to 28th December of last year:

```
touch -m -t $(date -d "$((RANDOM%$(($(date +"%Y") - 1970 - 1))+1970))-$((RANDOM%12+1))-$((RANDOM%28+1)) $((RANDOM%23+1)):$((RANDOM%59+1)):$((RANDOM%59+1))" '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

It is not perfect (doesn't generate a day higher than 28 or this years' dates), but should be good enough for most cases.

Inspired by https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/random-date-generator-784598/